# How to shift focus from webpage to modal dialog using python selenium using generic way

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, automation, browser-automation

I'm working on codeless automation POC. There are few buttons on website which are easily identifiable by the python selenium. I just clicked on "Signup" button then a new layer is coming on top of the basic webpage. Now selenium is not identifying the text on the new layer. How to shift focus to the new layer so that we can easily access the text. The new layer is a div block.

Note: Example purpose I'm adding this image as we are working on the client website. In this you can find once click "Sign up" button from right sight a new layer is came and covered the default page, actually it's a div block now selenium python is not able to identify "Phone number","Name" ..etc on that layer.[image]

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://xyzwebsite.com")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='{Text}']")))
element.click()
```

Any generic solution to shift focus from basic webpage to the new layer so that can access text and other fields as I cannot take manual Xpath or ID. Any suggestions are appreciated. Thank you.